# access ENV_INJECT variables in Jenkins job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am unable to access any Jenkins environment Variables inside the groovy script of a JobDSL.  I can see values of system environment variables.

Here is the groovy script I am running:

`println(System.getenv("HOME"))
println(System.getenv("WORKSPACE"))`

Here is the output:

`/users/s051464
null`

I have tried setting environment variables using Environment Injection and that doesn't work either (all set variables are null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `${VAR_NAME}`, [more info here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#access-the-jenkins-environment-variables). One exception is node specific variables such as `WORKSPACE`, in those cases you need to do the following ([from here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#list-the-files-in-a-jenkins-jobs-workspace)):

```
 hudson.FilePath workspace = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()
```